# App Localization: different language every second launch!

Tags: ios, localization

I'm testing my app on the iOS simulator.
I have two files of Localizable.strings - one for Italian and one for German. In each of them I have accordingly:

```
"Updating..." = "Aggiornamento in corso...";

"Updating..." = "Daten werden aktualisiert...";
```

In the code I do:

```
NSString *updatingString = NSLocalizedString(@"Updating...", nil);
```

Now when the language in the settings of the simulator is set to German, every SECOND launch of the app the value of updatingString is "Updating..." and every other second launch it is "Daten werden aktualisiert...".

For the Italian language it is always correct and the value of updatingString is always "Aggiornamento in corso...".

Can anyone explain this magic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Apparently I had multiple localization files, some of them came within the ShareKit library. It contained strings for german language too. So every second launch the simulator picked the ShareKit's localized string file, every other second launch - my own.

Strange though that XCode didn't let me know about the existing conflicts...